# How to kill Finished threads in python

Tags: python, multithreading

My multi-threading script raising this error :

```
thread.error : can't start new thread
```

when it reached 460 threads :

```
threading.active_count() = 460
```

I assume the old threads keeps stack up, since the script didn't kill them. This is my code:

```
import threading
import Queue
import time
import os
import csv


def main(worker):
    #Do Work
    print worker
    return

def threader():
    while True:
        worker = q.get()
        main(worker)
        q.task_done()        

def main_threader(workers):
    global q
    global city
    q = Queue.Queue()
    for x in range(20):
        t = threading.Thread(target=threader)
        t.daemon = True
        print "\n\nthreading.active_count() = "  + str(threading.active_count()) + "\n\n"
        t.start()
    for worker in workers:
        q.put(worker)   
    q.join()
```

How do I kill the old threads when their job is done? (Is return not enough?)

Comment: `threader` is an infinite loop.. but I don't see how you are creating more than 20 threads here. Does this exact code really raise that error?

Comment: i'm calling main_threader(workers) from another script normally without threads .

Comment: So, you're calling it repeatedly? OK, well, where does the `threader` function ever exit? `main` calls `return`, but that just goes back to `threader`, which continues with the `while True` loop.

Comment: the main function is doing a scraping work , and worker parameter is a link to scrape.

Comment: is there is a way to kill all the threads who finished their work ?

Comment: Actually, I just noticed `global q` - are you trying to share 20 threads between all calls to `main_threader`?

Answer (score 0):

Your `threader` function never exits, so your threads never die. Since you're just processing one fixed set of work and never adding items after you start working, you could set the threads up to exit when the queue is empty.

See the following altered version of your code and the comments I added:

```
def threader(q):
    # let the thread die when all work is done
    while not q.empty():
        worker = q.get()
        main(worker)
        q.task_done()        

def main_threader(workers):
    # you don't want global variables
    #global q
    #global city
    q = Queue.Queue()
    # make sure you fill the queue *before* starting the worker threads
    for worker in workers:
        q.put(worker)  
    for x in range(20):
        t = threading.Thread(target=threader, args=[q])
        t.daemon = True
        print "\n\nthreading.active_count() = "  + str(threading.active_count()) + "\n\n"
        t.start() 
    q.join()
```

Notice that I removed `global q`, and instead I pass `q` to the thread function. You don't want threads created by a previous call to end up sharing a `q` with new threads (*edit* although `q.join()` prevents this anyway, it's still better to avoid globals).

Comment: great , now the threads is not stacking , but i'm working with just 2 threads now ?

Comment: I suspect your work is happening too quickly for more than one thread to actually be active at one time. Now that the queue is filled before the threads are created, it's possible that the first couple of threads finish the entire queue before you've finished creating the rest of the threads. You could try adding `time.sleep(1)` to the `main` function, see if you see more simultaneous threads.

Comment: the main function is taking way more then 1 second, it's not possible that threading.active_count() returning also the finished threads ? cause it keeps incrementing for each new thread .

Comment: If it keeps incrementing, what makes you think you're working with just 2 threads?

Comment: sorry i was talking about the results before the last modification , after the modification it's just 2 threads from threading.active_count() , and the terminal ("ps -o nlwp <python ID>")

Comment: i'm sure the old threads work is done as i printing the results , but i'm not sure why they still active afterward , any direct way to kill a thread after it finish his work ?

Comment: It should just die when you `return` from it. When I run this code, I don't see `threading.active_count()` going up. It actually only gets to 7, strangely. Perhaps it's a platform-specific thing. The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects) say that `join` waits until the thread terminates, so I would not expect dead threads to stick around.

Comment: yeah i'm getting "Can't create new thread" error after it reached 450 threads in one of my vps , but the script works great in another vps with different provider (4000 threads now with no problem , but it's not normal since i'm working with a pool size of 20) .

Comment: Well, that's weird. With my code that only shows 2 threads, does CPU usage indicate more than 2 threads? I mean, if you have 8 cores maxed, then there are more than 2 threads active. You really don't need more threads than you have CPU cores anyway, 20 is probably overkill.